# Reload page if user has no javascript enabled

Tags: php, javascript, html

is there way to reload a web-page, when javascript is disabled in the brwoser?

I mean, if the user visits the page first time, and has no javascript enabled, the page reloads with a get parameter like page.php?js=false.

Maybe, thanks for hints.

Comment: it is impossible to do reload iof javascript is enabled ? on page.php?js=true - and remember it in session ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way you could force a page reload, without javascript, is by use of a meta refresh tag. However, this is the wrong way to go: better display that page for the javascript-deprived, and redirect those who DO have javascript to a more appropriate page instead.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, basically the OP just needs to do the opposite of what hes thinking.

Comment: You run into race conditions - the meta redirect could fire before external javascript finishes loading, and get a false redirect because the not-yet-loaded javascript failed to kill the redirect.

Comment: ok, thats a point. and google does not like the meta-refresh tag?

Comment: Don't know, offhand. I leave the SEO worries to others. There's plenty of legitimate reasons for meta refresh, though, so I can't see Google penalizing its use.

Comment: How can you kill the redirect with javascript?

Comment: You can't, which is another drawback to your method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252743/using-javascript-to-override-or-disable-meta-refresh-tag

Answer (score 3):

```
<noscript>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=page.php?js=false" /> 
</noscript>
```

You can use `<noscript>` tag with [`refresh` `<meta>` tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm).

Comment: @Ilyssis: I am not sure about Google :)

Comment: btw. one content-tag too much

Comment: @Ilyssis: Fixed did not notice that. Note that `2` is time in seconds, you can adjust that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Sarfraz's post, you could do this, to match your request:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=page.php?js=false">
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the other way around:

Assume javascript is not available, and
redirect using javascript to `page.php?js=true`.