# Is Meta Refresh Redirect "Secure"

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, meta, noscript

I have a line of code that redirects the user from `index.php` to `enable-js.php` if they block Javascript:

```
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=enable-js.php"></noscript>
```

Since this is a client side redirect, is it still possible for a user to still access `index.php` to do something like fill out a form while they have javascript disabled, or should I find a way to implement PHP `headers` instead?

Comment: They could in this case enable javascript and fill out a form on index.php, if that's what you meant

Comment: I mean if they still have javascript disabled...I'll edit the question

Comment: It's possible to turn off JavaScript **after** the DOM has been loaded (without a refresh), so yes, it is possible to bypass your `<noscript>` and still have JavaScript turned off. However, I'm not exactly sure what you're **trying** to do in the first place, and this is beginning to sound like an like an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: _"to do something like fill out a form while they have javascript disabled"_ - am I correct in interpreting that as you thought that validating your data client-side via JavaScript was enough, as long as you kept "non-JS" users away from the form ...? It'd be really naive if you'd expect any request reaching your server-side script would have to come from something like a "browser" to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since this is a client side redirect, is it still possible for a user to still access index.php to do something like fill out a form, or should I find a way to implement PHP headers instead?

Yes. They could script it via cURL (which won't process a meta refresh at all), cancel the navigation (by pressing escape really quickly, for example), or [disable meta refresh in the browser entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720461/is-it-possible-to-disable-meta-refresh-in-google-chrome).