# Disable HTML auto-refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, refresh

A client's website has an auto-refresh feature which works great for desktop sites, but I'm making an iPhone app and need to disable it on the mobile version.

The code used is:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="30">
```

I would like to use javascript to disable it, if possible.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I DO NOT have access to the HTML file, and therefore can't modify it. I need to do this via code on the Objective-C side in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a UIWebView to display the site, you could use `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"..."];`, where "..." is this javascript:

```
    var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
    for(var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) {
        if (metaTags[i].getAttribute("HTTP-EQUIV").match(/^REFRESH$/i))
            metaTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(metaTags[i]);
    }
```

Condensed down to one line for convenience:

```
var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName("META"); for(var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) { if (metaTags[i].getAttribute("HTTP-EQUIV").match(/^REFRESH$/i)) { metaTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(metaTags[i]);}}
```

Edit: Well...after all that, turns out it's not possible to cancel an existing refresh request by simply removing the meta tag from the document.  Once the parser sees the meta tag, it will refresh regardless of any javascript trickery you do.  Unfortunately, the only way to overcome this is to modify the HTML page directly.

Comment: I get what you mean, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it. I've used stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString before, but not to change or remove a value.

Comment: You should just be able to copy-paste the one-liner above into stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, and that will remove the bad meta tag from the HTML page.

Comment: So this is what I have. It's not working. I'm not sure if I did the escape sequence right for the quotes.

[myWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName(\"META\"); for(var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) { if (metaTags[i].match(/^REFRESH$/i)) { metaTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(metaTags[i]);}}"];

Comment: I forgot one important thing -- the if statement needs to compare the value of the "HTTP-EQUIV" attribute, not the tag itself.  I modified the code above.

Comment: Using this, still not working: 
        [myWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName('META'); for(var i = 0; i < metaTags.length; i++) { if (metaTags[i].getAttribute('HTTP-EQUIV').match(/^REFRESH$/i)) { metaTags[i].parentNode.removeChild(metaTags[i]);}}"];

Answer (score 1):

I will introduce something simple

Add `meta` tag with ID `id="meta-refresh"` like this:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;http://new-url/" id="meta-refresh">
```

Just use these script..

```
 var iOS = false,
     p = navigator.platform;
 if( p === 'iPad' || p === 'iPhone' || p === 'iPod' ){//remove which is not your target
     iOS = true;
 }
 if(iOS){ // check if iOS then do the following
      var mr = document.getElementById("meta-refresh");
      mr.parentNode.removeChild(mr);
 }
```

I believe this will work..

Also, the initiated request which JavaScript can not disable once loaded!!
For the same, the exact work around one can find in an [`Old Post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252743/using-javascript-to-override-or-disable-meta-refresh-tag) answer given by user `XP1`

The above is using xmlhttp requrest (AJAX) to check before the document is loaded and remove the meta tag if the device is target device(iphone)

OR

one can use refresh dynamically id the device is not iPhone/iOS. that will remove the requirement of doing the dynamic check and requirement to avoid first refresh call. without using meta tag

```
 var iOS = false,
     p = navigator.platform;
 if( p === 'iPad' || p === 'iPhone' || p === 'iPod' ){//remove which is not your target
     iOS = true;
 }
 if(!iOS){
      window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.href=window.location.href},30000); //30 Seconds
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer: **window.location.reload = () => {}**

longer answer:
most browsers support some modification of a function that refreshes a web page.
the one here was tested on Chrome.

Disclaimer: this will remove the page reloading functionality entirely for a given page.