# Meta Refresh not working in Firefox

Tags: html, meta-tags

I'm using meta refresh with `<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0; URL=javascript:window.open('home.asp?uuid=123','_top');">` and it works in every other browser except Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you just do <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home.asp?uuid=123"> ?

Comment: it needs to replace the parent window url

Comment: It's strange how it works in Chrome, Safari, and even Internet Explorer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690253/meta-refresh-redirect-to-top-frame it seems similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox autorefresh has been disabled by default.

To enable autorefresh in your browser:

1. type **about:config** in the location bar of your webbrowser
2. a message appears: click to accept
3. search for *blockautorefresh*
4. change *accessibility.blockautorefresh* from **false** to **true**

Good luck!

Comment: The option blockautorefresh has default value false, so autorefresh is enabled by default (at least in FireFox 23).

Answer (score 0):

```
accessibility.blockautorefresh TRUE
```

does not stop HTML or Java-based refreshes - it's quite common for webmasters to pimp their page hits by chain refreshing, typically at 1 second intervals. I learned about `accessibility.blockautorefresh`, celebrated, changed the value and was sorely disappointed that it didn't work for HTML / Java based refreshes.

I absolutely despise web developers who use my equipment to falsify page hits for monetized reasons. Every other major browser can manage it. I use Firefox specifically because of the level of control it gives and love Firefox muchly, but I am forced to go back to Internet Explorer until Firefox catches up.

Answer (score 0):

Just put (id) that you require within the Action element in a form like this:

I tried in PHP code..

```
$q = $_GET['id'];
...
echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=home.php?q=".$q."' />";

<form role="form" action="home.php?q=<?php echo $q; ?>" method="POST">
```