# Why does meta refresh not work in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, meta, page-refresh

My page contains this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.example.com">
    </head>
    <body>
        test
    </body>
</html>
```

It redirects in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Why not?

Comment: @Kaiido Whatever this is issue was has probably been changed - this was asked several months ago, so it's about an earlier version of firefox, unfortunately I can't recall which

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meta Refresh not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908063/meta-refresh-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 4):

In Firefox autorefresh has been disabled by default.

To enable autorefresh in your browser:

1. type **about:config** in the location bar of your webbrowser
2. a message appears: click to accept
3. search for *blockautorefresh*
4. change *accessibility.blockautorefresh* from **false** to **true**

It would be best to use alternatives such as a JavaScript or PHP Redirect.

**JavaScript**

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}, 5000);
```

**PHP**

```
header("refresh:5;url=wherever.php");
```

Comment: My version of firefox says taht it is set to false by default. So, this is not it.

Comment: Changing it to true doesn't do anything. Strictly speaking, I believe it is supposed to show a popup asking to redirect if it set to true, so it seems firefox is ignoring that value entirely.

Comment: I've got it set to false by default and it does work on my FF39 on a mac

Comment: Step #4 is backwards in my case, the correction is to change _accessibility.blockautorefresh_ from **true** to **false**

Answer (score 4):

On Firefox the auto refresh is disabled by default.

You can configure Firefox manually by entering *"about:config"* in the browser's address bar. A warning message will appear; click on *"I'll be careful, I promise!"* to be able to continue.

Next, type *"Accessibility.blockautorefresh"* in the search box at the top of the page. Double-click the *"true"* value next to this preference to set it to *"false"* and allow the browser pages to auto-refresh.

Or use Javascript to redirect to the page.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
}, 2000);
```

Or you can add one line code to the body tag:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(location.href='https://www.google.com/', 2000)">
```

Comment: My version of firefox says taht it is set to false by default. So, this is not it.