# javascript reload

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am using a web site that annoyingly refreshes its content every so often. How could I prevent that using javascript's greasemonkey firefox plugin ?

---

Edit:

- I am indeed not able to change the source code of the server.
- The
  site I'm talking about is indeed a news site. Here is such an
  example:
  http://www.lemonde.fr/ameriques/article/2013/03/08/aux-etats-unis-le-cout-social-dramatique-des-coupes-budgetaires_1845220_3222.html

Comment: I don't really know where to start, sorry, I'm not a web developer, I'm just a greasemonkey user

Comment: There are quite a large number of ways in which content can be "refreshed", so your first task is to find out how it's achieving the refresh, then interrupting that.

Comment: I added a link to the website. I'm not very savvy in web development, but I found a xtRefresh and xtReload function in the source that could be related.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little barbaric, but if you can get access to the source code, look for any instance of `location` within the javascript, and then comment it out with `//`.

Something like

```
location.reload();
```

thus becomes

```
//location.reload();
```

---

This is less likely, but the refresh could also be in the `HTML`. So be on the lookout for this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

If you *do* happen to find that, you can either delete the line, or comment it out with `<!--` and `-->`

```
<!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> -->
```

Note that this might prevent the page from updating and cause the user to need to manually refresh every so often to view new content.

If you want the page to refresh its content without reloading the page, you *could* find a developer who is experienced in AJAX to turn it into an asynchronous webapp, which would eliminate the need to refresh, but that is a whole 'nother discussion.

---

Hope this helps

---

**EDIT**

I looked through the site, and in the elements, I found a `<meta>` tag which causes a refresh every `900` milliseconds (or 900 seconds?).

In chrome:

- Hit F12
- Go to the left-most tab (`elements`)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Type `refresh`
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Right click the node that gets highlighted
- Click `Delete Node`

This will stop the page from refreshing for the lifetime of the currently loaded copy of the page. If you refresh or navigate to another page on the site, you have to rinse and repeat, but at least it will stop it from refreshing.

Comment: You do need to look for those things, but remember that the OP has no access to the server.  He cannot "edit the source code" like that.  You'd need to show how he could combat the refresh/reload on the client side and that's not a trivial problem.

Comment: @Brock How exactly do you know that? OP never explicitly said he didn't have admin access to the server. Maybe he does, maybe he doesn't. Anyways, assuming he doesn't have admin access to the server, it is still possible to track down where the refresh is happening in javascript and rewrite the function with the reload commented out using a javascript console. While this is only for the lifetime of the client, it would still solve the problem temporarily and prevent the page from refreshing, thus saving a lot of frustration. My answer does assume admin access, though :/

Comment: You know he doesn't have access to the server, because there is no  reason to use Greasemonkey, otherwise.  His tone talking about "using" "a web site" is also strongly indicative that he has no controlling association. ... And, no, it is not always possible to use the console to stop a reload timer.  In fact, in most cases it is NOT possible, since such timers tend to be protected by scopes and/or anonymous code.  You certainly can't stop a `<meta>` after the fact. ... This kind of thing *should* be possible with Greasemonkey, but it is nowhere as easy as this answer currently implies.

Comment: @Brock As a web developer, why in the world would you set a page to reload every x seconds? This seems like it has no practical purpose... Let's hope the site doesn't use a `meta` tag to refresh.

Comment: Really? This is an *extremely* common technique used by news sites, weather sites, portal sites, or just sites looking to cram more ads down your throat.  Remember the the vast majority of sites are not AJAX-ified.  Even today, a periodic refresh may still be the smart, cost-effective way over AJAX.  Or, just a fallback if the client blocks AJAX features.

Comment: @shkra19 I've edited my post with an easy way to delete the meta tag on your client copy.

Comment: @Brock Eww, The site actually *did* have the `<meta>` refresh tag. I personally try to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this seems to help. However I don't want to have to manually disable refresh on every page that I go to. This is where the greasemonkey part of my question comes in. How could I use greasemonkey to delete this meta node ?

Comment: This recipe **does not work!**  Deleting a `<meta>` tag after the page has loaded will not stop the refresh, at least on most browsers and certainly not on Firefox (the Greasemonkey default browser).  Also `content="900"` is 900 seconds or 15 minutes. ... You can test this on [this page](http://jsbin.com/uxumoh/1).

Comment: I see... So what would you suggest ?

Comment: @shkra19, believe it or not, this is not a trivial problem.  I have an idea for something that might work. If it doesn't then you need to find or make an extension.  I'll post an answer if it works out, but this is a low priority.  Might be a day or two, if at all.  (Or somebody else could figure it out.)

Comment: Yes sorry I have no idea of how difficult this might be, I'm not a web developer. But thanks a lot for your help, I'll be waiting.

Comment: @Brock Hmm, I did not know the meta tag persists even after deleting it. In that case, I'm making this post community wiki so anyone can easily edit it.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to my question :(

Comment: @shkra19 it doesn't look like there's an easy, user-friendly way. There's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252743/using-javascript-to-override-or-disable-meta-refresh-tag), but it involves lots of javascript.