# Remove meta tag refresh

Tags: jquery, refresh, meta-tags

My site has a refresh tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='400'>
```

I have some vídeos embedded and when they're playing I want to remove the refresh.

In a specific function that detects when video is playing I did this using JQuery:

```
$("meta[http-equiv='refresh']").remove();
```

But the page still refreshes after 400 secs.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252743/using-javascript-to-override-or-disable-meta-refresh-tag/13656851#13656851

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing the meta tag isn't an option, based on the link Robert Rozas added --> [Using Javascript to override or disable meta refresh tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252743/using-javascript-to-override-or-disable-meta-refresh-tag/13656851#13656851)

Since I don't have your code I can't help completely, but below is a way to auto refresh the page on load & then stop refreshing it on an event.

Clicking on the Test Button will stop the refresh.. just hook this into your event and it should solve your problem -->

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#test").click(function (e) {
        // This event will clear the timeout
            clearTimeout(timeout);
     });

 var timeout = setTimeout(function()
{
    // The refresh is occurring here
    location.reload();
}, 4000);

});
 </script>
 <button id="test">Test</button>
```

The following will remove the meta tag (quotes removed)

```
 $('meta[http-equiv=refresh]').remove();
```

Comment: Not the downvoter but the page still refreshes after appearing to remove the `<meta>` tag from the DOM, at least in Firefox.

Comment: Well done @ejhost!This solve the problem. Tkanks for everybody's help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `<noscript>` tag? Also, if the .remove function does remove the `<meta>` from the DOM, then you should make sure that it's not something else refreshing your page!