# Can I stop a meta refresh using javascript?

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

The following code allows the user to stop the meta refresh from happening - and it successfully removes the `meta refresh` from the page, but the browser nonetheless refreshes the page. Any idea how to make it work?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" id="refresh" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#refresh").remove();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Reloaded at <span id="time"></span>
<script>
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = Date();
</script> 

<a href="#">Stop refresh</a>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: this is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252743/using-javascript-to-override-or-disable-meta-refresh-tag) because that question wants a fallback solution for users not supporting javascript - this is not the case for me (most of the answers to that question do not apply to this question).

Comment: You can't, the meta tag has been parsed on page load, any change to that is ignored after that.

Comment: I don’t have an answer to your question but may I ask why meta refresh is used in the first place?

Comment: An aside: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh

Comment: I found tricky answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13656851/2818869

Comment: Some of the answers to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3252743/2818869) seems to be just "stop the meta refresh from happening", even the question do not match your case.

Answer (score 18):

Just for completeness and not my recommended way. You could call:

```
window.stop();
```

To stop loading the window. Internet Explorer doesn't support this and you have to to this:

```
document.execCommand("Stop");
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, this worked great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll be able to do this because the header is read when the page is loaded and the browser will schedule the refresh. I do not think the browser gives you a way to cancel that since it's effectively an HTTP header, not part of the document. It would be better to add an onload handler for the body element that uses a timer to schedule the refresh, then have your click handler cancel the timer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  var timer;

  $('body').on('load', function() {
      timer = setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
  });

  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (timer) {
       clearTimeout(timer);
       timer = null;
    }
  });

  function refresh() {
      timer = null;
      document.location.reload(true);
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I put the `var timer` outside off `$(function(){` and removed the `$('body').on('load', function() {});`. Then it was nice!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me wonderful! (tried in chrome)

```
<button onclick="pauseshow()"><img id="myImg" src="images/pause.jpg" width="45" height="45" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:1200px;" ></button>
function pauseshow()
{
    window.stop();
    //  Below did not work --> 
    //  var mr = document.getElementById("mymetatag");
    //  mr.parentNode.removeChild(mr);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not able to remove the header later via javascript since the reload is triggert while loading the page. But deferred by 5 sec.

Instead you could change the way of thinking and reload the page with javascript instead of the meta tag:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = window.location;
}, 5000);
$(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Reloaded at <span id="time"></span>
<script>
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = Date();
</script> 

<a href="#">Stop refresh</a>


</body>
</html>
```