# meta refresh and saving process conflict

Tags: javascript, html

Can there be a conflict between `<meta refresh>` and save process that waits 5 seconds before executing ajax post?

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
</head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the meta refresh can interupt the ajax request. To get around this. When you start to wait 5 seconds for the ajax post request. Maybe call:

`document.execCommand("Stop");` OR `window.stop();` This will stop the page in its tracks and should (in theory) allow you todo your ajax request without a refresh occuring.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435865/can-i-stop-a-meta-refresh-using-javascript) for a similar question.

Another way of getting around this issue would be to refresh the page every 30 seconds using javascript rather then a meta refresh. This way, you'll have full control over the refresh.

Comment: For the 30 seconds option toward the end of reply, would I use a setTimeOut to do this?

Comment: Yup! `setTimeout(function(){ //do refresh here }, 30000);`

Comment: If I use document.execCommand("Stop") or window.stop, when the saving is done, how would I start the auto-refresh again?